# unable to fetch text from the modal dialog using getText() method before accepting the alert

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

On clicking this link in the image shared, a modal pop up window opens which i am able to switch to click the OK button but cannot fetch the text present in it. The modal dialog is shared in the screenshot and has no html tags hence i cannot locate 
the text in it using any locator.
I tried using driver.switchTo().alert().getText() to fetch the text present in it.

[image]

Comment: Which binding are you using ?

Comment: sorry did not get what binding means assuming its the platform i am using java

Comment: I am getting the following exception if I try to capture the text before accepting the alert:java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteAlert.getText(RemoteWebDriver.java:1079)

Comment: Any suggestions will be helpful.Its a little urgent.

Comment: But my question is different I have editted the question as well

Comment: Hi, @DebanjanB kindly unmark it as duplicate as my question is a little different from the one that you referred.Please check.

Comment: @titli0216 Can you please edit the question and update the community how is this question different from the dup marked discussion? Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB i went to the question that you referenced but did not find the answer to my query hence I requested you to unmark this question as duplicate I have already edited the question, earlier I was unable to switch to the alert and accept it but now using alert.accept() I am able to click the OK button in the alert but cannot fetch the text in the popup. The question which you have referenced has nothing mentioned about fetching the text inside the popup. In case, I am missing out anything can you please point out the part which you are asking me to refer. I will be really helpful.

Comment: @titli0216 Thanks. Reopened.

Comment: Thanks  DebanjanB

Comment: DebanjanB any suggestions regarding my query. I tried debugging as well but getting the ClassCast Exception but not sure why to cast as it is already a string.If I do not use getText() I am able to make the code click the OK button but if I use getText() before alert.accept(), the code fails.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not an _Alert_. While you address any user please append `@` in the beginning else intended user isn't notified.

Comment: @DebanjanB ok sure I will take the suggestion

Comment: Any help from the community members will be appreciated as this is a little urgent. This is a javascript popup i guess.

Comment: I tried using the following code.Can anyone confirm if this is the right approach as the text is getting printed now:

Comment: if (isAlertPresent()) {
   try {    
    JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("window.confirm('my text')");    
    Alert confirmation=driver.switchTo().alert();
    String alertText=confirmation.getText();
    logger.info("Alert text is:"+alertText);
    if(alertText.contains("my text"))
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Comment: @Rajagopalan: Any suggestions from your side?

Comment: I would suggest you to move to WATIR

Comment: Please find my code below:
try {                      
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            /*System.out.println(alert.getText());
            if(alert.getText().contains("Parent BOM Acid TST2101 001 is in different RDOs that the user may not belong to"));*/
            alert.accept();
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: @Rajagopalan: Sorry did not get what you meant WATIR????

Comment: I use WATIR for my automation which sits on the top of Ruby selenium Binding, which has all the waiting properly. It would rescue for element invisible,staleelement, and also it has good syntax. And also while it handles alert, it waits for the alert to appear!

Comment: @Rajagopalan I am actually using Selenium java. Will it work for java as well?

Comment: No, it wouldnt.

Comment: Ok thanks@Rajagopalan